# Dual Power Supply Switch?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

So the question is short, how do i connect a single switch to a circuit that has a dual power supply (+/-) connected to it?
Or do i have to use an special kind of switch?

Comment: Can you explain your problem more? The switch is use to switch the power supply?

Comment: The switch os used to turn the circuit on and off

Comment: What's your two power supplies voltage?

Comment: They are both 12v

Comment: DC 12V? Then how much current will flow in them? And do you want to manual control or use MCU to control the switching?

Comment: I dont have that info, if you need it i will meassure it in the morning, it shouldnt be much, no more than 1 mA and should be less

Comment: Manual control or digital control?

Comment: Manual Control Switch

Comment: Can you use a DPST switch?

Comment: Sure, i just wanted to know if can do it with a single one so i dont have to find a Dual, cause its a little hard to find ot in the area, but if there is no other option ill try to get it

Comment: Or two mechanically linked SPST switches, which is what a DPST switch is internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a **double-pole** switch. That's a bit like having two switches in one. A double-pole switch will simultaneously switch two separate circuits.